# PyMySQL Parametrized Query and Date Format

Tags: python, mysql, escaping, pymysql

I'm trying to run the following query using PyMySQL

```
cur.execute("SELECT %s as label, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%%Y-%%m-%%d-%%H:%%i:00'),DATETIME)) as time, %s  as metric FROM %s WHERE id >= %d GROUP BY label, time", (label, metric, table, min_id,))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

label, metric, table, and min_id are a string, string, string, and int, respectively.

Am I not escaping the %'s correctly?  Can't quite figure this out, have tried a few things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`... id >= %d ...` should be `... id >= %s ...`.

All parameters are escaped converted to strings before applied to the format string.

Comment: But.... but.... whhyyyyy?????  Try `select * from users limit %d;` as your query!

Comment: No, that won't work, only if you do `cur.execute('select * from users limit %d' % (10,))`, which uses string formatting instead of sql parameters and **is potentially dangerous**.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how is inserting an integer into an SQL query dangerous? It's not like `10; drop table users;` is an integer.

Comment: I didn't mean that using an integer is dangerous but that generally using string formatting to construct sql queries is. In this case it wouldn't be a problem, but imagine you'll later need to add some where clause with a string parameter, and overlook that you used string formatting instead of sql parameterization. Suddenly you have a potential sql injection vulnerability...